# Разбор задачи с несколькими условиями If

Tags: python-3.x, if, условия, операторы

> Задача

Представьте, что вы подбрасываете два кубика одновременно. Считайте с входящей строки два целых числа d1 и d2. Проверьте, соответствуют ли введенные числа интервалу значений для кубика. Если нет, то выведите на экран строку "Ошибка! Значение на кубике (1 или 2, вставьте подходящее значение) не входит в интервал [1, 6]". В противном случае посчитайте сумму выпавших значений. Если сумма равна 7 или 11, выведите на экран "Я победил!!!". Если сумма равна 2, 3 или 12, то выведите на экран "Я проиграл :(". Во всех остальных случаях выведите на экран сумму значений.

Задачу попытался разбить для себя на два этапа: с условием интервала [1,6] и попытаться написать код без привязки к нему

1)Начал со второго

```
n1 = int(input())
n2 = int(input())
sum = x + y
if sum == 7 or 11:
   print('Я победил')
elif sum == 2 or 3 or 12:
  print('Я проиграл')
else:
  print(sum)
```

И тут, собственно, проблемы: если поставить 'or' между 7 и 11 - всё время пишет "Я победил". Если заменить на 'and' - 7ка в сумме даёт print('Я победил'), а 11 - выкидывает на print(sum)

Объясните, пожалуйста, нюансы многоуровневых условий

Comment: Кстати, код в вопросе - нерабочий уже на строчке sum = x + y.

Comment: @Эникейщик Почему?

Comment: Скопируй код, запусти. Поймёшь почему.

Comment: @Эникейщик Если бы я знал, "почему" у меня не работает полностью код (который, кстати, отсутствует в соответствии с условиями задачи, а только написана часть его), я бы не просил объяснить мне что я не так делаю. Ссылка на вопрос "python и правила строчного or" только даёт малую часть ответа на поставленный мною вопрос: к примеру, она не даёт ответы как грамотно записать с помощью кода все поставленные в задаче требования. Так что, не совсем понимаю, почему вопрос был закрыт.

Comment: @Bizzarro Прочитайте все ответы.  Там описано и как объединить  условия, и как использовать in при большом количестве вариантов

Comment: А вы и не спрашивали "как грамотно записать с помощью кода все поставленные в задаче требования". Вы озвучили проблему с ``or``. Она разобрана в вопросе и ответах по ссылке, поэтому вопрос закрыт как дубликат.

Comment: @Эникейщик А если снова задать вопрос с просьбой объяснить как грамотно записать ответ по всем условиям, это не будет слишком "общий" вопрос?

Comment: Смотря как задать. На самом деле у вас все почти правильно. Надо только расширить на другие значения. Ну и можно поискать здесь другие решения, похожие вопросы уже задавались.

Comment: @Эникейщик :) Понял! Сейчас попробую всё исправить: в ссылке действительно даётся практически полностью ответ на мой вопрос, кроме соединения еще с условием попадания в интервал. Подскажите, пожалуйста: это условие нужно "запихнуть" в эти же операторы или в подобных случаях поступают как-то иначе?

Comment: Можно и иначе, но и if-elif достаточно.

Comment: @Эникейщик Получилось: спасибо! По крайней мере, на выходе вроде всё правильно. На всякий случай напишу код, который получился: вдруг что-то найдёте некорректное                 
n1 = int(input())
n2 = int(input())
summa = n1 + n2
if 6 > n1 > 1 and 6> n2 > 1:
  print('Ошибка')
else:
  if summa == 7 or summa == 11:
    print('Я победил')
  elif summa == 2 or summa == 3 or summa == 12:
    print('Я проиграл')
  else:
    print(summa) После первого цикла второй идёт уже внутри: вроде результат правильный.